# Error in scala IDE

Tags: eclipse, scala

I not really understand what this error means? This is occur when I delete some source file. Is there any good IDE for scala development beside eclipse?

[image]

Comment: Scala IDE (which is based on Eclipse) is a good one. Recently, I started using Intellij IDEA, which is a great tool as well. However, I wouldn't give up just like that. If fjr.plugin.ChangeCurrentFrame is missing, than it could be that the source code didn't compile. Check if automatic re-build is enabled, or something along that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete a file, sometimes the IDE doesn't catch that it needs to recompile, and so it gets confused about what happened to the file.

To fix, go to `Project` -> `Clean...` and clean the project.  This will force it to inspect the files and recompile.